# DiscordJS Bot - Getting the json from a site

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a discordjs bot that outputs the lowest_price when a certain command is done from this steam market search  [Site to get the data from](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=252490&currency=1&market_hash_name=Alien%20Red) I just am not to sure on how to actually pull the data from it, I would very much appreciate someone to help and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like `node-fetch` or `axios`:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// client is your Discord.js client
client.on('message', async (message) => {
     if (message.content === 'lowest') {
         const res = await fetch('https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=252490&currency=1&market_hash_name=Alien%20Red');
         const data = await res.json();
         // data is your json!
         message.channel.send(data.lowest_price);
     }
});
```

Comment: Will look into both of them, Thank you!